# GHC 8 - Constrained type parameterization rules with renamed functions

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-parameter

I'm puzzled by a seemingly buggy behavior of GHC happening with rather simple Haskell programs.

Consider the following code:

```hs
import System.IO
output :: [String] -> IO()
output stringList = sequence_ $ map putStrLn stringList

main :: IO ()

s = show

main = output [
    s 42,
    s True
  ]
```

In GHC 8.4.3 produces the following output:

```
$ runghc parameterize.hs
.hs:9:7: error:
    • No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘42’
    • In the first argument of ‘s’, namely ‘42’
      In the expression: s 42
      In the first argument of ‘output’, namely ‘[s 42, s True]’
  |
9 |     s 42,
  |
```

GHC 8.0.2 produces the same error.

This also happens with the following variations:

- Using `where`

  ```hs
  main :: IO ()
  main = output [
      s 42,
      s True
    ]
    where s = show
  ```
- Using `let ... in`

  ```hs
  main :: IO ()
  main = let s = show in output [
      s 42,
      s True
    ]
  ```

But in the three cases, replacing `s = show` by `s x = show x` solves the problem:

```hs
main :: IO ()

s x = show x

main = output [
    s 42,
    s True
  ]
```

```hs
$ runghc u.hs
42
True
```

This is not specific to `show`. Here is one which fails with the `succ` function operating on `Enum` elements:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = let s = succ in putStrLn $ showList [
    show $ s 41,
    show $ s False
  ] ""
```

Replacing `s = succ` by `s x = succ x` still fixes the thing.

I haven't been able to find an explanation for this unexpected behavior. Is it a bug ? If it isn't, please explain what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are bitten by the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) and its not a bug. The first two paragraphs of that page:

> The "monomorphism restriction" is a counter-intuitive rule in Haskell
>   type inference. If you forget to provide a type signature, sometimes
>   this rule will fill the free type variables with specific types using
>   "type defaulting" rules. The resulting type signature is always less
>   polymorphic than you'd expect, so often this results in the compiler
>   throwing type errors at you in situations where you expected it to
>   infer a perfectly sane type for a polymorphic expression.
>
> A simple example is plus = (+). Without an explicit signature for
>   plus, the compiler will not infer the type (+) :: (Num a) => a -> a ->
>   a for `plus`, but will apply defaulting rules to specify plus ::
>   Integer -> Integer -> Integer. When applied to plus 3.5 2.7, GHCi will
>   then produce the somewhat-misleading-looking error, No instance for
>   (Fractional Integer) arising from the literal ‘3.5’.

Simply replace `(+)` here with `show` and it is your example.

With this code for example:

```
import System.IO
output :: [String] -> IO()
output stringList = sequence_ $ map putStrLn stringList

main :: IO ()

s = show

s2 x = show x

main = do
  output [
    s False,
    s True
   ]
  output [
    s2 42,
    s2 True
    ]
```

You get this result in ghci after loading the file containing this:

```
Prelude> :l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> :t s
s :: Bool -> String
*Main> :t s2
s2 :: Show a => a -> String
*Main>
```

So in your first example the type deduced for `s` doesn't allow you to use it with a number.

The exact rules, when the monomorphism restriction applies are defined here [Section 4.5.5 of Haskell Report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5), but are fairly technical.

Also pay attention that the monomorphism restriction is deactivated at the ghci prompt and only applies to compiled modules.

Comment: To be explicit, the solution is to either provide the polymorphic type signature (`s :: (Show a) => a -> String`) or add the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of the file (or equivalently `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` on the command line or `NoMonomorphismRestriction` in the `extensions` field in a Cabal file or `package.yaml`).